# How do i get a json string in js from a jquery ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Why is the console log: {}
I have a in js the following ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
     url: '.../models/user.php',
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: "json",
     data: {username: username, password:password, func:func},
     success: function(data) {
           console.log(data); 
     }
});
```

and in my user.php

```
switch ($_POST['func']) {
    case 'register':
        $user = new User();
        $a = $user->register($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
        $b = json_encode($a);
        echo $b;
        break;
}

class User {

    private $username = '';
    private $password = '';

    Function register($user, $code) {


        //..database things...

       if(succes){
        $newUser = new User();
        $newUser->username = $user;
        $newUserInJason = json_encode($newUser);
        return $newUser;
       }
    }

}
```

the console log is only {} but I want the User object in JSON. Am i missing something?

Comment: because you have your dataType set to json, when set it to that jQuery will automatically parse JSON text to an object. If you just want the text change dataType to text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use json_encode on a class, the private properties of that class will never be visible.

So if you change:

```
    private $username = '';
    private $password = '';
```

to:

```
    public $username = '';
    private $password = '';
```

the outcome will be:

```
{
    username: "some-user-name"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the method json_encode passing a Class object.

For php convert a Object to Json, you must implement the interface JsonSerializable: [JsonSerializable inferface doc](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.jsonserializable.php)

In that way you could use json_encode passing a object without any problem
The method implementation you use the following code:

```
get_object_vars($this)
```

So you User class must looks like this

```
class User implements JsonSerializable{

// Interface method you must implement:
public function jsonSerialize(){
    return get_object_vars($this);
}

// The rest remains the same

private $username = '';
private $password = '';

Function register($user, $code) {


    //..database things...

   if(succes){
    $newUser = new User();
    $newUser->username = $user;
    $newUserInJason = json_encode($newUser);
    return $newUser;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should return `$newUserInJason`